# UIActivityViewController make UIBarItem in inputAccessoryView disappear?

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, uiactivityviewcontroller

I use UIToolbar as inputAccessoryView of UITextView, there are some UIBarItems inside it.

```
self.toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];

NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *bold = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"B" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(bold)];
UIBarButtonItem *italic = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"I" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(italic)];
UIBarButtonItem *underline = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"U" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(underline)];

[items addObject:underline];
[items addObject:italic];
[items addObject:bold];

self.toolbar.items = items;

[self.textView setInputAccessoryView:self.toolbar]
```

These items work OK, but when UIActivityViewController active, then dismiss in iOS6 simulator, these items are disappear, only blank toolbar display.

What's the reason? Please help!